# Discord bot to kick users based on role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Good Afternoon,

first off I apologize for my lack of knowledge when it comes to Java Script. I am trying to fill a need for one of our servers without exactly knowing how :D The end goal is to kick a user once they received a specific role called "Inactive".

Figure i'd start with creating a bot that kicks a user if you 'kick @username'. These are the files I have:

Config.json:

```
{
"token": "(mytoken, which i'm obviously not posting :D)"
}
```

Index.js:

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'kick'){
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
        }

});

client.login(token);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "kickbyrole",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Bot to kick based on discord role",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Tri",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^0.12.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.3.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.28.0",
    "discord-prefix": "^3.0.0",
    "discord.io": "^2.5.3",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "winston": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

kick.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
        }else{
            message.channel.send("You couldn't kick that member");
        }
    }
}
```

I can "node ." to initiate it without error. My bot shows online.. but nothing happens when I try to !kick @username.

Two asks.. a) what am I missing for my bot to work and b) what do I need to change for it to kick based off user role? So like 'kick @role'

Appreciate all your time and help!

Cheers

Tri

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a user from a voice channel I think it's not `memberTarget.kick()` but perhaps `memberTarget.setVoiceChannel(null)`.

to kick all users I think what you could do is get all the users that contains this role and run a forEach function

```js
message.member?.guild.roles.cache.
find((role) => role.name === "Inactive")?.
members.
forEach(m => m.voice.setChannel(null))
```

If you want to make it into a fully working bot I would do like this:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

const prefix = "!" // mention the prefix

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
});

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;


    const args = message.content.replace(prefix, "").split(" ");
    const cmd = args[0].toLowerCase();
    args.shift();


  if (cmd === "kick") {
   const role =  message.member?.guild.roles.cache.find(
    (role) => role.name === "Inactive"
  );
  role?.members.forEach((m) => {
    m.voice.setChannel(null);
    m.roles.remove(role);
  });
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

now when you run `!kick` it should kick every user that has Inactive role and remove the `Inactive` role from the user.

Comment: I want to remove from the server all together. Also I don't understand syntax enough to be able to turn one line into a working bot xD Apologies

Comment: Okay haha I get it, first thing I've changed my line and tried it, it should work now

Comment: I've updated my answer with a description of how it should look like try it and let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: Hrm.. I put your code into my index.js, however I changed "AFK" in the code above to "Inactive" because that is what the role is called. Then I did "node ." to initiate it. I do "!kick" and absolutely nothing happens :D

Comment: Okay I've added some changes please try again :)

Comment: Still does nothing

Answer (score 0):

To kick all the users who have the `Inactive` role, is pretty simple. All you have to do is go through all the users with the role and then kicking them. You can get all the members of the guild by using `message.guild.members` and then you can kick them by using `member.kick()` The code might look something like this:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith('kick')) {
    const mentionedRole = message.mentions.roles.first() // Gets the mentioned role
    const usersWithRole = mentionedRole.members // Gets all the members with the role
    usersWithRole.forEach((user) => { // Go through the collection of members
        user.kick().then(m => { // Kick them
            message.channel.send(`Kicked ${m.user.tag}`)
        })
    })
}
```

In this case, the bot will first get the mentioned role, then get all the members who have the role, go through each member and then kick them one by one. If instead of getting the mentioned role, you just want to always kick the users with the `Inactive` role, you can replace the `mentionedRole` variable with this:

```js
const mentionedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Inactive')
```

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem, please accept the answer as it will help people to see the correct solution for your problem